# Get product description that isn't in an order

Tags: sql, t-sql

- There's a table of `Products` that has `p_no` and `p_desc`.
- There's a table of `order_details` that has `p_no` (same as above).

I need the `p_desc` where `products.p_no` is not in `order_details`.

Note: I have done many searches and this is what I came up with as the result.

```
-- Why would this work?
select p_desc from products
except
select p_no from order_details

-- Then,
select p_desc from products
where products.p_no not in order_details.p_no

-- and finally,
select p_desc from products
where (p_no not in (select p_no from order_details))
```

Are any of these right? I was told to use `except`, but I don't see how the first statement is comparing the `p_no` property, so I'm assuming that this is wrong.

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx

Comment: Questions from any source (including homework) are welcome on Stack Overflow, as long as they meet the criteria for all questions (clear, concise, code to repro the problem, attempted solutions and research, etc). No need to mention it's homework, in fact, try to leave it out and make the question stand on its own as a great programming question (one that can be useful to others that don't have your specific assignment as well) to make sure it meets mentioned criteria.

Answer (score 1):

Because this is homework I'm not going to spell it out.

> // Why would this work?
>   select p_desc from products
>   except
>   select p_no from order_details

See: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx
Hint: the following code is equivalent:

```
SELECT p.p_desc FROM products p
LEFT JOIN order_details o ON (o.p_no = p.p_no)
WHERE o.p_no IS NULL
```

> // Then,
>   select p_desc from products
>   where products.p_no not in order_details.p_no

That looks like syntax error.

> // and finally,
>   select p_desc from products
>   where (p_no not in (select p_no from order_details))

Looks good and I find this one the easiest to understand.

**Remarks on Microsoft's `EXCEPT`**
Whilst I can see the ease of use argument, using code like that will make it very hard to port your code to another platform.
I recommend staying closer to the core of SQL-92 and use the form in your last statement.
It will make you a more all-round programmer and prevent lock-in to a single platform, which can only be a good thing as far as job prospects go.

From a functional point of view code sample A offers no benefit over sample C, both take the same amount of time to run.

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way is to use `NOT EXISTS`. I just answered a similar question here:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/51270/get-unmatched-rows-for-foreign-key

(Note that that answer is for MySQL, however the T-SQL syntax is the same.)

In your case that query would look like this:

```
SELECT p_desc FROM dbo.products AS P
 WHERE (NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.order_details AS OD WHERE OD.p_no = P.p_no));
```

Comment: That's not an answer. It should be a comment. The OP asked "how does EXCEPT work".

Comment: Thank you very much! May I ask what the function of "1" is in the second select?

Comment: Despite your (it seems unfounded) belief in your own knowledge, far from being the "cleanest" solution, this is very likely the worst. See @Johan's answer for a solution that most would consider the cleanest.

Comment: @MichaelDiLeo, `NOT EXISTS` checks if any rows are returned by the inner select. It does not care about columns or column values. You could use a * or mention any column name. I usually use the constant 1 in this case.